# How do we know when Heritrix completes a crawl job?

Tags: heritrix

In our application, Heritrix is being used as the crawl engine and once the crawl job is finished, we are manually kicking off an endpoint to download the PDFs from a website. We would like to automate this downloading pdf task as soon as the crawl job is complete. Does HEritrix provide any URI/webservice method - which returns the status of the job? (or) Do we need to create a polling app to continuously monitor the status of the job?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is any option to do it without continious monitoring but you can use [Heritrix API](https://webarchive.jira.com/wiki/display/Heritrix/Heritrix+3.x+API+Guide) to get status for a job, smth like

```
curl -v -d "action=" -k -u admin:admin --anyauth --location -H "Accept: application/xml" https://localhost:8443/engine/job/myjob
```

gives you XML from where you can read job status.

Another, maybe easier (yet not so 'professional') option is to check if your jobs warcs directory contains a file with .open extension. If not - the job is finished.

Comment: That's correct. Curl provides a way to do several actions. However, there should be another endpoint which returns the job status - this is the basic operation provided by any jobs frameworks, except Heritrix. I tried to hit the https endpoint - localhost:8443/engine with params createpath=testjob&action=create from POSTMAN client but could not connect due to SSL certs may be? Any ideas?